# Webpack attempts to load a module, which I didn't ask it to load and fails. How to debug?

Tags: webpack

Webpack is one of the most frustrating tools I've seen in a long time. It's got circumambulating documentation and it's very un-friendly and non-interactive. If it fails - it's like a black box - no way you can interact with it and ask what's wrong.

I have my configuration mostly working, but with a single annoying warning, I can't get rid of. The warning looks as if some module tried to `require` `index.html` and seems like default javascript loader just can't parse it:

```
WARNING in ./app/index.html
Module parse failed: /home/burkov/Documents/Projects/bostongene/workflows/workflows/workflows/frontend/app/index.html Line 1: Unexpected token <
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <html>
|     <head>
|         <base href="/">
 @ ./app \.html$
```

My configuration has `index.html` explicitly excluded in `ngtemplate` loader:

```
...
module: {
    ...
    loaders: [
        ...
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            exclude: `${path.join(__dirname, "/app/index.html")}`,
            loaders: [`ngtemplate?relativeTo=${__dirname}`, "html"] //html?attrs[]=div:ng-include
        }
    ]
}
```

Without this exclude I get an error like [this](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin/issues/212).

. I'd like to find out:

1. Who (what line of code) attempts to load the `index.html` module, resulting in warning?
2. What loader is responsible for loading this file?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, what a relief!

There's a very nice tool in Webpack, which generates callgraphs and even explains, what loaders were used to load each file:

http://webpack.github.io/analyse/

So, [as Sokra instructed](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/690), we generate a callgraph json with `webpack --profile --json > stats.json`, and paste this json to that webpage (or just read it carefully). The tool generates a nice interactive callgraph:

[image]

In my case it turned out that I required all the html templates in my project (including `index.html`, stupid me), which I explicitly excluded from ngTemplateLoader, so the generic javascript loader tried to load it and failed.